# dpkg: error processing package skype:i386

Tags: skype

```
dpkg: error processing package skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
```

Comment: Enable Canonical Partner and [install skype from there](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the installation instructions for Ubuntu should specify that git, git-man, and liberror-perl are required with brave.deb, and suggest including a line if they are not already installed | sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: this seems to be a useful comment rather than an answer. Could you expand with full steps?